# Why the Oplog decreasing Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, debugging, nosql, mongodb-oplog

What type of query generates a decrease in the oplog? How do I find out which queries are affecting my oplog decrease (when comparing month to month)? Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Oplog window is affected by heavy write queries  and particularly mass deletes of big size documents  since single range delete operation  disolve in the oplog as multiple individual delete queries.